# GKE Cluster - Understanding 'EndPoint'?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I have created a GKE cluster. I did a describe of of my cluster as below:

`gcloud container clusters describe dev-gke --region=us-east4 | grep 35.245.72.197`

and the output is as below:

```
endpoint: 35.245.72.197
  publicEndpoint: 35.245.72.197
```

As a novice in GCP, it would be great if veterans can help me understand, what is this public endpoint for ?

Answer (score 2):

The `publicEndpoint` is the external IP address of this cluster's master endpoint. The master endpoint is the IP address for the Kubernetes master node.

Note: The correct (better) command to obtain the public endpoint:

```
gcloud container clusters describe [CLUSTER-NAME] \
    --zone=[ZONE] | --region=[REGION] \
    --format="get(privateClusterConfig.publicEndpoint)"
```

Comment: great to know that. I do have some follow up questions:
- How do i access my master node using this public end point? I do not see anything in the UI.
- What if i disable the public endpoint?

Comment: @Sunil - Stackoverflow is not a discussion forum. Post a question, select and check good answers, post a new question, get more answers.

Answer (score 2):

As John said for other questions please open a new thread.

> The master node is manage by GKE directly.
>
> https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#master

Here you can find more information about setting a private cluster:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/authorized-networks